# Intellisense error when using `__FUNCTIONW__`

Tags: visual-c++, macros, intellisense

I am using the `__LINE__`, `__FILEW__` and `__FUNCTIONW__` macros to aid in the writing and implementation of a custom exception class.  As is well known, they automatically provide the line number, source-file name and function name of the location in code from where they are called.  Also, as I am working exclusively in Unicode I must use the **...W** wide character versions of those that expand to a string result.

For example:

```
throw CEString(CEString::ERROR_INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS,
                __LINE__,
                L"End index is smaller than start index",
                L"Index Out of Bounds",
                __FILEW__,
                __FUNCTIONW__,
                L"CString");
```

Where `CEString` is a custom exception class whose Constructor takes two integer arguments and then five simple wide strings to locate and describe the error for which it is thrown.

I have the header files `iostream`, `new` and `crtdefs.h` properly included.  Going from the documentation the latter should not be strictly necessary, but as it is where the macros are actually defined I have included it anyway.  However, the *Intellisense* error-checker in **VS2013** highlights my use of the `__FUNCTIONW__` macro as an error.  It returns the following notification:

*Error: identifier L__FUNCTION__ is undefined.*

...which is strange!

Where this becomes even stranger is; the programme itself - despite this error warning - compiles happily and what is more even runs as expected.  The supposedly debatable macro creates its wide-character function-name expansion without any complaint.

So this is obviously a problem with *Intellisense*, not the code or headers.  Do any of you chaps have an idea what might be going wrong?

This is probably the closest previous question :

[Why would __FUNCTION__ be undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482297/why-would-function-be-undefined)

However, unlike Ben Voight I find the programme does actually link and run!  The problem is explicitly with Intellisense.

Comment: This is [a known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873138/intellisense-does-not-recognize-builtin-preprocessor-macros).

Comment: Add that as an answer @Hans Passant and I will tick it!  That link you give seems definitive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is already made public to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873138/intellisense-does-not-recognize-builtin-preprocessor-macros).

Intellisense generally seems to have problems with macros even in VS2010 ( self defined or built in )

You should be okay ignoring the error for now.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991828/boost-in-visual-studio-2010-intellisense-error) might give you some insight in what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can just define the following (preferably in your PCH header)...

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1800 && _MSC_VER <= 1899)
#define L__FUNCTION__ nullptr
#define L__FILE__     nullptr
#endif
```

It's a useless definition, but it stops IntelliSense from reporting the "*undefined*" expansion.