# How can I avoid: identifier "L__FUNCTION__" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've got a log macro that looks something like this:

```
#define LOG(formatString, ...) \
{ Log( TEXT(__FUNCTION__) TEXT(" ") ## formatString TEXT("\r\n"), ##__VA_ARGS__);  }
```

It compiles and works fine, however it seems to trip up visual studio intellisense which underlines all uses of the macro in red with the error:

```
IntelliSense: identifier "L__FUNCTION__" is undefined
```

I'm thinking of raising this to microsoft, but in the meantime, is there a workaround that is as efficient at runtime which will not trip intellisense up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellisense error when using \`\_\_FUNCTIONW\_\_\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745594/intellisense-error-when-using-functionw)

Comment: You don't want to workaround that, you want to fix it. You want `__FUNCTION__` expanded before the concatenation. Two levels of macro expansion is the usual cure for such.

Comment: Hmm, thought I'd solved it by using an expand macro, but I actually just ended up with the text "__func__" instead of it being expanded.